# SQL querying the same table twice with criteria

Tags: sql

I have 1 table

table contains something like:

```
ID, parent_item, Comp_item
1, 123, a
2, 123, b
3, 123, c
4, 456, a
5, 456, b
6, 456, d
7, 789, b
8, 789, c
9, 789, d
10, a, a
11, b, b
12, c, c
13, d, d
```

I need to return only the parent_items that have a Comp_item of a and b 
so I should only get:

```
123
456
```

Comment: If you want parent items for a and b shouldn;t the result set be 123, 456,  789?

Comment: @RyanWilson, 789 has no a.

Comment: @jarlh Oh, I see now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a canonical way to do this:

```
SELECT parent_item
FROM yourTable
WHERE Comp_item IN ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY parent_item
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Comp_item) = 2
```

The idea here to aggregate by `parent_item`, restricting to only records having a `Comp_item` of `a` or `b`, then asserting that the distinct number of `Comp_item` values is 2.

Comment: But... what if it has two 'a' instead of 'a' and 'b'? This query will show it, and it shouldn't.

Comment: What does `COUNT(DISTINCT Comp_item)` return if there are 5 `a`'s and 5 `b`'s?  Answer: It still returns 2.

Comment: `and it shouldn't` ... where do you see that requirement listed?  I see it nowhere.

Comment: I would not have thought of `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Comp_item) = 2`. And this can be dynamic easiliy with the `IN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use `INTERSECT`:

```
select parent_item from my_table where comp_item = 'a'
intersect
select parent_item from my_table where comp_item = 'b';
```

Comment: Interesting answer +1.  I wouldn't have thought this way, as not all databases have an intersect operator.

Comment: The problem with this kind of solution is when you need to add also `comp_item  'c'` but also `d`, ... `z`.

Comment: Yes, this solution requires **multiple** scans of the heap (or luckily just the index). Still, multiple scans, one per value. I hear you.

Comment: @Impaler . . . Given that the alternative uses `group by`, multiple scans isn't such a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a parent item table, the most efficient method is possibly:

```
select p.*
from parent_items p
where exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.parent_id = p.parent_id and t1.comp_item = 'a') and
      exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.parent_id = p.parent_id and t1.comp_item = 'b');
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `t1(parent_id, comp_item)`.

I should emphasize that I very much like the aggregation solution by Tim.  I bring this up because performance was brought up in a comment.  Both `intersect` and `group by` expend effort aggregating (in the first case to remove duplicates, in the second explicitly).  An approach like this does not incur that cost -- assuming that a table with unique parent ids is available.